# Multiplied rows in impala

Tags: sql, impala

I am fetching some data from a view with some joined tables through sqoop into an external table in impala. However I saw that the columns from one table multiply the rows.
For example

```
id first_name surname step name       value
1  ted         kast    1   museum     visitor
1  ted         kast    1   shop       buyer
1  ted         kast    2   museum     visitor
1  ted         kast    2   shop       buyer
```

But I want to be something like that

```
id first_name surname step name_value
1  ted        kast    1    [(museum visitor), (shop buyer)]
1  ted        kast    2    [(museum visitor), (shop buyer)]
```

How can I achieve that in impala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use aggregation here along with `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    first_name,
    surname,
    step,
    CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', CONCAT_WS(' ', name, value), ')'), ', '), ']') AS name_value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id,
    first_name,
    surname,
    step
ORDER BY id;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdf4c614dc0d58b4b3191d34a1c0bc4e) for MySQL, where the syntax is almost the same as for Impala.